# Getting profile pic from Facebook and display it in Android App

Tags: android, image, facebook, bitmap, request

I'm trying to get a users facebook profile pic using the FB api.

My way of doing this isn't working... first I make a request like this:

```
String str = facebook.request("me/picture");

Next I create an inputstream from the string str so I can decode it with a bitmapfactory

InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes());

Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

This never displays the image!
Haven't been able to find much about this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I fixed this by just using HTTPGet to the url 

The first time I tried it I got a 404 error but when I rewrote it it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by just using HTTPGet to the url The first time I tried it I got a 404 error but when I rewrote it it worked!